# How to calculate acceleration from power and weight?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, power

Imagine a bike that is not moving initially at $t=t_0$.  The bike and its cyclist have a combined mass of $m=60\,\mathrm{kg}$.

If the cyclist starts to apply $p=100\,\mathrm{W}$ of power, then what would the acceleration $a$ be after 1 second, at $t=1\,\mathrm{s}$?

Answer (score 3):

100 Watts * 1 second = 100 Joules. Assume (best case) all is converted into kinetic energy and no friction nor air resistance.

Kinetic energy = $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$

Solve for $v$

Comment: You may want to mention how to calculate $m$ from $w$.

Comment: @Nat OP said the bike and cyclist are 60 kg. kg is a unit of mass.

Comment: Ohhh good point!  They said "_weight_", but you're right, $\mathrm{kg}$ is a unit of mass, so that's probably what they meant.